# Flutter YouTube Player Closed Captions Not Supported

Tags: flutter

I am using [youtube_player_flutter plug-in](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter). However, it does have option to turn on/off closed caption. Is it possible to do so with this plug-in? If not, is there any other plug-in can support CC?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem; although the official description of youtube_player_flutter plugin claims that it supports captions, the player did not have the "CC" icon and I couldn't figure out how to enable/disable or change the captions.

However, the [youtube_player_iframe](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_iframe) package seems to support closed captions. In the player there's a three-dot icon on the lower left, which, when clicked, allows you to enable/disable or change the language of captions. The player also has a more complete set of controls which I could not find in the youtube_player_flutter package.